# Python random mouse movement and clicking event

Tags: python

I am making a bot for a game. So far I have built the basics I need for my game. Now I want to get it a little bit further and make a mechanism that will randomly move the mouse within a range on my screen and click that position. How I am thinking it, I will set the top left, top right, bottom right, bottom left cords and pointer will mouse within that range and when it gets to the position it will do a click and after some time it will move to another random position. Any suggestion how I should start?

Comment: Please try building something yourself, then if you're stuck or getting errors , create a question..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [pymouse](https://pypi.org/project/PyUserInput/) to get screen resolution and control your mouse, and [`randint()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.randint) to choose random coordinates to click at

```
from pymouse import PyMouse
import random
import time

m = PyMouse()
x_dim, y_dim = m.screen_size()

while True:
    m.click(random.randint(0, x_dim), random.randint(0, y_dim))
    time.sleep(2)
```